# I'd like to wrap std::array to create a circular array but how to provide aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, c++14, stdarray, aggregate-initialization

With `std::array` you can do

```
std::array<int,3> v = {1,2,3};
```

But I want to provide a wrapper

```
template <typename T, int n> circular_array {
   auto operator[](size_t i){
       return m_data[i%n];  
   }
   // TODO forward all other methods directly except ``at`` which we don't need
 private:
   std::array<t,n> m_data;
}
```

but I lose the aggregate initialization that I had above for `std::array`. This will not work.

```
circular_array<int,3> v = {1,2,3};
```

though if I made `m_data` public I could do

```
circular_array<int,3> v = {{1,2,3}};
```

which is not desired.

Is there a way to achieve `circular_array` as a drop in for `std::array` including aggregate initialization?

Comment: Ditch the private member? If you want aggregate initialization it entails having an aggregate.

Comment: Have a look at the [requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) on cppreference. Short answer: no.

Comment: Maybe I'm being too specific here for the language lawyers in asking for aggregate initialization. Is it possible to write `circular_array<int,3> v = {1,2,3}` using some method?

Comment: You can provide variadic template constructor `template<typename ... x_Initializer> circular_array(x_Initializer ... initializer): m_data{initializer...} {}`

Comment: What about this? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list I've never used it before.

Comment: You need a compile time size and an initializer list has runtime size like a vector. Since C++14 there is `constexpr size_type size() const noexcept;` but I'm not sure how this could solve the problem.

Comment: Do you want to be able to use class template argument deduction `circular_array v = {1,2,3};` like in `std::array v = {1,2,3};`?

Comment: Can you use inheritance rather than composition? That is, why not just *derive* your `circular_array` from `std::array`, rather than have a `std::array` data member. That could work.

Comment: I don't think I'm able to use class template argument deduction in C++14 anyway but as we will update to C++17 in the next year or so then it would be nice.

Comment: @AdrianMole will this inherit the aggregate constructor?

Comment: Hmm. Well, `circular_array<int, 3> v = {1,2,3};` compiles, but with a warning: *suggest braces around initialization of subobject [-Wmissing-braces]* (clang).

Comment: A colleague pointed out that the way std::array achieves the same goal is by not hiding it's implementation C array as private but instead makes it public and it ``just works``

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it's exactly what you're looking for, but you can use *inheritance* (that is derive your class from `std::array`) rather than *composition* (i.e. having a `std:array` data member).

Here's a demo:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int n>
class circular_array : public std::array<T, n>
{
public:
    auto operator[](size_t i) {
        return std::array<T, n>::data()[i % n];
    }
};

int main()
{
    circular_array<int, 3> v = {1,2,3};
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        std::cout << v[i] << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tested this code in Visual Studio (Windows) and it works as expected; the native MSVC compiler gives no diagnostic (even in code analysis mode) but clang-cl issues the following for the aggregate initialization (which it doesn't give when using such syntax for a native `std:array` object):

> warning : suggest braces around initialization of subobject
> [-Wmissing-braces]

Not being a Language-Lawyer, I'm not sure if this means that the `circular_array<int, 3> v = {1,2,3};` line is **truly** still aggregate initialization; but, if it's not, then I'm equally unsure what it is.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with -std=c++14 but does work with -std=c++17. Something changed. https://godbolt.org/z/TMG8f33fE

Comment: @bradgonesurfing Ah! My bad. However, I'll leave the answer here (for now) so that when (if) you upgrade to C++17 (next year?), you can come back and use it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to realize that [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) has to pull off the same trick. It does this by making it's single member public rather than hiding it.

[image: msvc std::array]

So the (partial) solution is

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T, int n>
class circular_array 
{
private:
static
    constexpr int Wrap(int kX) noexcept
    {
        if (kX < 0)
            kX += n * (-kX / n + 1);

        return kX % n;
    }

public:
    typename std::array<T,n>::reference operator[](int i) {
        return m_data[Wrap(i)];
    }
    std::array<T,n> m_data;
};

int main()
{
    circular_array<int, 3> v = {1,2,3};

    std::cout << v[-3] << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[-2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[-1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << v[3] << std::endl;


    return 0;
}
```

which outputs

```
1
2
3
1
2
3
1
```

which works all the way down to `c++11` as far as I have tested. I still have to implement all the other forwarding calls but the principle is clear though kludgy.

https://godbolt.org/z/Kqhsa8cP5